# how do you summarize data in oracle based sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle table called login that has a column name as_time and the entry is timestamp(6) data type:

```
15-NOV-16 11.01.43.255000000 AM
```

I need a select statement that counts the number of records every 15 minutes for last 30 days.

Output needs to be like this:

```
Time                 Count
11/01/2016 00:00:00   10
11/01/2016 00:15:00   10
11/01/2016 00:30:00   50
11/01/2016 00:45:00   70
11/01/2016 01:00:00   10
11/01/2016 01:15:00   10
11/01/2016 01:30:00   10
11/01/2016 02:45:00   160
```

Can somebody help with constructing the sql query?

Comment: Do you have Calendar table or something like that ?

Comment: @Prdp, the table has other columns but the most important one is the as_time, I just have to count the number of records every 15 minutes.

Comment: Am not taking about this table. Do you have any other table which has list of dates ?

Comment: @Prdp, no other table

Comment: Do you have some input data?

Comment: Every 15 minutes for the last 30 days... does that mean the last 30 calendar days ending at midnight YERSERDAY? (Not including the fractional day today?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to truncate to the nearest hour and then deal with the minutes separately:

```
select trunc(as_time, 'HH') as yyyymmddhh,
       floor(extract(minute from as_time) / 15)*15 as mm,
       count(*)
from t
group by trunc(as_time, 'HH'),
         floor(extract(minute from as_time)
order by 1, 2;
```

Notes:

- You can combine the minutes and hours back into a timestamp column if you like.
- This only returns time periods where there is data.
- This does not include `as_date > sysdate - interval '30' day`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - rounds the timestamp down to the nearest 15 mins and then summarises :

```
WITH
 test_data (as_time) AS
 (SELECT 
   CAST(sysdate + (rownum/24/60) AS TIMESTAMP)
  FROM 
   all_objects
  WHERE rownum < 150
 )
SELECT 
 TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(date_hour||':'||mins_rounded_down,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI'),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')  rounded_date
,COUNT(*)
FROM
 (SELECT 
   as_time
  ,TO_CHAR(as_time,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')   date_time
  ,TO_CHAR(as_time,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24')      date_hour
  ,TO_CHAR(as_time,'MI')                    real_mins
  ,TO_CHAR(MOD(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(as_time,'MI'))/15)*15,60),'FM00') mins_rounded_down
  FROM
   test_data
 )
WHERE 1=1
AND as_time > sysdate - 30
GROUP BY
 date_hour
,mins_rounded_down
;
```

Comment: I've assumed you want to round down.  If you want to round to the nearest use ROUND instead of FLOOR.  If you want to round up use CEIL

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've extracted the parts of the date, except the minutes and seconds (using `to_char` for example) - all is left is basically to deal with the minutes.

If tbl is the dataset after the "extraction", and you don't care addressing the date as a string (you can always covert it using `to_date`), here's a suitable SQL query :

```
select dt_without_mins||floor(to_char(dt, 'mi') / 15) * 15, count(*) 
from tbl
group by dt_without_mins||floor(to_char(dt, 'mi') / 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. Create a time table in a subquery, join based on time comparisons, and group by/count; the join is a left outer join for data densification (time intervals with no activity are still included, with a count of 0).

```
select t.time_from, coalesce(count(*), 0) as ct
from   (
         select trunc(sysdate) - 30 + (level-1)/(24*4),
                trunc(sysdate) - 30 + level/(24*4)
         from   dual
         connect by level <= 30*24*4
       ) t
       left outer join login l
       on l.as_time >= t.time_from and l.as_time < t.time_to
group by t.time_from
order by t.time_from
;
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach is this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MakeInterval(ts IN TIMESTAMP, roundInterval IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC IS
    denom INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(24, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
    ELSIF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
    ELSE
        denom := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM roundInterval);                
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
    END IF;
END MakeInterval;



select 
   MakeInterval(as_time, INTERVAL '15' MINUTE) as time,  
   count(*) AS count
from the_table
where as_time > sysdate - 30
group by MakeInterval(as_time, INTERVAL '15' MINUTE);
```